# java applet not grabbing focus in JRE 1.6.0_29 and up (OS X)

Tags: macos, applet, java

A Java applet has the following in its start() method :

```
this.setFocusable(true);
this.requestFocus();
```

When launched, the applet grabs the focus only in certain OS/JRE/browser configurations. It's compiled using JDK 1.6.0_18, and on my PC running Java 1.7 it grabs focus in all browsers (Ie, chrome, Firefox) without problems; even if the applet is compiled using JDK 1.7.

On Mac OS X 10.6.8 which comes with Java 1.6.0_29 it doesn't grab focus in Safari, Chrome or Firefox, but the applet loads fine. When I upgrade the the Mac OSX JDK to the preview 1.7 - it doesnt' load the applet at all. If I compile the applet using JDK 1.7 and run using JRE 1.7 - it just crashes the browsers on the Mac.

Has anyone come across similar problems? thanks.

Comment: @Rene Please only post actual answers to questions as answers. If you continue to participate on the site you will eventually be able to post comments on questions.  I've converted your answer into a comment this time for you.

Comment: No Rene, I didn't find a solution. There doesn't seem to be a solution on the net, while the problem seems to affect not just myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs. for [`Component.requestFocus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus%28%29) state:

> Because the focus behavior of this method is platform-dependent, developers are strongly encouraged to use [`requestFocusInWindow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29) when possible.

Is it *possible* to use the latter in this case?

> Has anyone come across similar problems?

Focus problems go hand-in-hand with embedded applets.  If you want more reliable focus behavior, launch the applet free-floating using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first solution, but it didn't really help. the applet grabs focus on PC but not on Mac running 1.6.0_29 . I will try w few different environments and get back.