# Heavyweight components on Mac OS x in Java

Tags: java, macos, focus, components

I have an application which basically consists in a applet that runs on the browser.
I've been validating this application for Mac OS X and I came across with a focus issue that does not happen in Windows or Linux.

The problem occur, for example, everytime I use a JFileChooser to select a directory to save a file. After I select a directory and press 'ok' in the JFileChooser, if I'm running the application in Windows of Linux, the focus go back to the applet from where I opened the JFileChooser.
But on Mac OS X when I finish using the JFileChooser and I close it (or press ok) the focus does not go back to the applet. In that case I need to click somewhere inside the Applet to get the focus back there. This happens not only when I use JFileChooser but also every time I use a 'heavyweight' component.

I wonder if this is a know issue and we need to deal with it using for example requestFocus()? Any of you had problems with this before?

Comment: focus + applet = problem in some OS or browser?  Color me entirely unsurprised.  Sun never bothered to specify many things related to focus and applets, so any behavior in any browser is 'correct'.  If you want reliable focus behavior, I recommend pulling your applet out of your web page and make it free floating using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  That should sort the focus problems.  Actually, come to think of it, if you're going to free the GUI from the shackles of the web page, you might as well just launch a frame using JWS. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Making the applet free floating is not an option in my case. The applet MUST run in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

"Because the focus behavior of this method is platform-dependent, developers are strongly encouraged to use [`requestFocusInWindow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29) when possible."

See answer here: [java applet not grabbing focus in JRE 1.6.0_29 and up (OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491070/java-applet-not-grabbing-focus-in-jre-1-6-0-29-and-up-os-x)

(I googled: "osx browser applet focus issues")

Comment: This solution does not work. I tried it before.
Something I noticed is that what looses focus when a heavyweight component is open is the browser itself.

Comment: Does this help? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html (search heavyweight)